# I need to pull data from the tables from that url and put them in a table and export to csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and why I am getting an index error. The goal is to pull the stock data from cnn money keeping it in the order and categories it is in.  I am also using pandas to export it into a csv but since there are 3 different tables i can get one table at a time to load onto a csv. how do i get all 3 to display?

```
import csv
    import requests
    import bs4 as bs
    labels=[]
    data=[]
    url = 'http://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/index.html'
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    table=soup.find('div',id='wsod_hotStocks')
    rows=table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        labels.append(str(row.find_all('td')[0].text)) 
        data.append(str(row.find_all('td')[1].text))
import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_html("https://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/")

    df[0].to_csv("data.csv",index= False)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the error you get

Answer (score 0):

Your error(`IndexError: list index out of range`) is coming because at some iteration your list is empty and in your case it's on first iteration.

I've found a simple way to save your scraped data in csv:

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
df=[]


url = r'https://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/'
tables = pd.read_html(url,header =0, flavor = 'bs4') 

#if you want to store only one table
#df= pd.DataFrame(tables[count]) 


#if you want to store all table
count=0
while count<len(tables):
    df2= tables[count]
    df.append(df2)
    print(df)
    count+=1
df = pd.concat(df)
#to store all data of dataFrame
df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)
```

**Output**

[image]

```
#Save only one column to csv
df.to_csv('data.csv', mode='w', columns=['Company'], index=False)
```

**Output**

```
Company
GE General Electric Co
F Ford Motor Co
CCL Carnival Corp
MRO Marathon Oil Corp
TWTR Twitter Inc
DAL Delta Air Lines Inc
LUV Southwest Airlines Co
NCLH Norwegian Cruise Line Holdings Ltd
BAC Bank of America Corp
HAL Halliburton Co
......
```

Comment: @Iradessa, Is this answer helpful?

Comment: yes this is very helpful. You are amazing. with adding the tables to the csv how would I add headers to break out the companies as Gainers, Losers, and Most Actives?

Comment: create a list of headers in your case `headers = ['Most Actives','Gainers','Losers']` then pass it in loop's first line as `df.append(headers[count])`, this makes sub list e.g.`[header_name,table_data]` now use `header_name` as header of dataframe and `table_data` as table data